# Remove file prefix in absolute path but prefix is also directory part

Tags: java, string, trim

I was wondering if there is any nice solution for the following problem:

Assuming I have a string with the absolute Path to a file and the file has the prefix "temp_".
I am able to trim the prefix with string.replaceFirst().

But if I am unlucky "temp_" is also part of the directory in that String.
How to make sure only the last occurence will get trimmed?

I can only think to parse it myself, but was wondering if there's magic left to do it a better way?

To be more precisely as example:

```
C:\Dump\sol1\temp_results\temp_2012-04-core.pcap
```

Should become:

```
C:\Dump\sol1\temp_results\2012-04-core.pcap
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have got it is a File id defo use @goldilocks' approach. But if for some reason you simply have it as a String, first thing that popped into my head is this:

```
    String target = "temp_";

    String fullPath = "C:/Dump/sol1/temp_results/temp_2012-04-core.pcap";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(fullPath);
    int end = fullPath.lastIndexOf(target) + target.length();

    System.out.println(sb.replace(fullPath.lastIndexOf(target), end, ""));
```

Comment: I just gave an example to make it more precisely, hope it's bit clearer what I was saying.

Comment: @goldilocks solution is the way you should. Mine was just the first to pop into my head.

Comment: even though goldilocks is true, assuming that I have no access to the File Object this would be a very nice way I have not thought of and makes me accept as answer. Anyhow goldilocks would also work if you got access to the File Object.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `Path.getFileName()`, only the base name of the file is returned (ie, it does not include any parent directory).  You can do your substitution with that and put it back together using other Path functions (see `getName()`, `subpath()`, etc) into either another Path or a single String.

Answer (score 0):

This is just another example How to do it.

devide total String into three parts.

```
1.substring till temp_ last occurence

2.last occuerence of temp_

3.substring after last occuerence of temp_
```

cancat 1+3 anyway I recommend @goldilocks solution